# Gstreamer is unable to play videos

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I ran the command. I have an ubuntu 18 running on arm64 with an external monitor connected to nvidia jetson xavier.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

However it doesn't do anything . neither does it play any video. Terminal return following line

```
 Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
 Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
 Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
 Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
 New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Comment: That means it is playing. Maybe on a screen you don't have connected? Or the default videosink sends to somewhere else.

Comment: I only have one screen connected to it though.

Comment: Update: This was solved when I used HDMI instead of a Display port